# want to create BottomSheetDialogFragment Like Atttache One

Tags: android, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment

i want my bottomsheet to behave like attached image in stages like default,dragged and close.[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

```
 public class ExampleFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
  
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pdf_view, container, false);
         //Views
         
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
                FrameLayout bottomSheet = d.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
                BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            }
        });

        // Do something with your dialog like setContentView() or whatever
        return dialog;
    }
 
   }
```

Comment: dialog should only drag when click on top image rather on dialog. and can you provide full example.